# ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin ' ' is not loaded fix?

Tags: mysql

I messed up when trying to fix an error in the webapp that I'm trying to develop. The previous error was

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I followed this fix

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

but foolishly entered my password in the **mysql_native_password** part.

Now I think that my LAMP server is destroyed. Everytime I enter

```
mysql -u root -p
```

the error from the **ERROR 1524** appears even when I put sudo.

Comment: try to reset your password https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: btw, your server isn't destroyed. This is recoverable. Following official documents like ^ will keep you out of trouble. If still stuck, expand your question to what you've covered, and the current state, and tag the question with your MySQL version.